# How we calculate the center point from the given coordinate? React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, heatmap

This is my JSON ARRAY

```
[
    {
      "northEast": "60.22352998843195,24.94705001539827",
      "southWest": "60.13500641212243,24.66432372755647",
      "_comment": "First of bigger views, this is just comment, don't use it in code"
    },
    {
      "northEast": "60.25583006469535,25.052094025408156",
      "southWest": "60.16739368515819,24.76936773756636"
    },
    {
      "northEast": "60.259833395882744,25.196786999980585",
      "southWest": "60.17140782564092,24.914060712138788"
    },
    {
      "northEast": "60.212448009374754,25.00376734695335",
      "southWest": "60.16820109990049,24.862404203032455",
      "_comment": "First of medium views, this is just comment, don't use it in code"
    },
    {
      "northEast": "60.21163769386681,25.0439312331336",
      "southWest": "60.16738969143272,24.9025680892127",
      "_comment": "Last of medium views, this is just comment, don't use it in code"
    },
    {
      "northEast": "60.190268017659626,24.972029980829788",
      "southWest": "60.17920440537793,24.936689194849563",
      "_comment": "First of small views, this is just comment, don't use it in code"
    },
    
        {
      "northEast": "60.18471960429552,24.95630341642265",
      "southWest": "60.17365412217261,24.920962630442425"
    },
    {
      "northEast": "60.17386547757727,24.972094346031998",
      "southWest": "60.162796337863156,24.936753560051773",
      "_comment": "Last of small views, this is just comment, don't use it in code"
    },
    {
      "northEast": "60.170494436844166,24.96379079865687",
      "southWest": "60.16495976522987,24.946120405666758",
      "_comment": "One really small"
    }
  ]
```

Now I want to Calculate the center point. When I click on any Coordinates It will get the Center point. Below is my code. I want to get the center point when i click any of the map area it will zoom in and show the center point. I also Attach the reference code given below.

```
const setTupleArray =()=>{
        var tupleArray: Array<LatLngTuple[]> = [];
        data.map((item)=> {
            const northEast =  item.northEast.split(",");
            const southWest = item.southWest.split(",")
            tupleArray.push([
                [+northEast[0], +northEast[1]],
                [+southWest[0], +southWest[1]]
            ])
        })
        let tupleAreaCalculateArray: any = [];
        tupleArray.forEach( (item: number[][]) => {
            const area =  calculateArea(item)
            tupleAreaCalculateArray.push([...item, [area] ])
        })
        const calculate = tupleAreaCalculateArray;
        setLatLngTupleArray(calculate);
    }

     // Calculate the distance area of layer 
     const calculateArea = (item: number[][]) => {
        var p = 0.017453292519943295;    // Math.PI / 180
        var c = Math.cos;
        var a = 0.5 - c((item[1][0] - item[0][0]) * p) / 2 + c(item[0][0] * p) * c(item[1][0] * p) * (1 - c((item[1][1] - item[0][1]) * p)) / 2;
        return 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `L.LatLngBounds` and use the built in `getCenter()` function: [Docu](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/reference.html#latlngbounds-getcenter)

```
var bounds = L.LatLngBounds([60.22352998843195,24.94705001539827],[60.13500641212243,24.66432372755647]);
var center = bounds.getCenter();
```

Comment: this will not helpful, when we have multiple json Array and we need to click on browser any of area it will not get center of every reactangle.
Please check the link below for better understanding.
https://react-leaflet-heatmap.herokuapp.com/